# How to implement/upload my own html and css code to weebly?

Tags: html, css, web-hosting, weebly

I made a custom website using html,css etc for a friend who is currently using a weebly platform template for their current website.

After agreeing to use my custom website, I have no clue on how to upload my pages to weebly and avoid using their templates. I've tried to clear the pages and then inputting my own html code and CSS, however, the CSS is not implemented and the html code itself is awkwardly placed. I have tried to google the problem, however, I cannot find any clear instructions or tutorials.

The only reason using I am weebly is because they are currently subscribed to it. So my question is how to use your own coded website with weebly?

Also if there are cheaper options of webhosting feel free to suggest them, since I'll need to use one for the future.

EDIT: I can run each page locally on my PC

Comment: I don't think it is available since it is website builder service or you can contact them directly here https://hc.weebly.com/hc/en-us/articles/204197083-Contact-Weebly-via-Phone-Live-Chat-or-a-Support-Ticket 

There are alot available webhosting with variate price and service. You can try search it first.

Comment: @ColourDalnet Okay, thanks for the reply. I'll look to webhost it somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer is, you can't. At least not the way you expect to be able to. Lots of platforms are like this.

That said, you can certainly convert what you've created to something that will work on the Weebly platform. Your Theme/Design, CSS and any custom JavaScript can be converted. The content itself is added using the Weebly editor.

I guess you should ask yourself; Who's going to be editing this website? And does the Weebly platform fit their needs. If it is your friend, and they already have a subscription, and the platform is sufficient for them, I would recommend converting it so it works with Weebly. ~And not create something that they can't manage later.